# Where should I declare an array containing 500 objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, large-data

I'm working on a project that will contain an array of about 500 different creatures. Each creature has 6 different attributes such as name, age, speed, etc.

I realize I will be spending a lot of time writing out each property for each creature, but I'm not sure if there is a more appropriate (and efficient) place for so much information. At first, I began writing some samples of the array in the `viewDidLoad` method, but I thought it might be more organized if I declare the array by itself inside a separate header file. Is that possible?

```
creatureList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:25];

Creature *creature = [[Creature alloc] init];
creature.name = @"Edward";
creature.age = 24;
creature.gender = @"Male";
creature.attack = 75;
creature.defense = 50;
creature.speed = 90;

creature = [[CreatureObject alloc] init];
creature.name = @"Bruno";
creature.age = 39;
creature.gender = @"Male";
creature.attack = 60;
creature.defense = 100;
creature.speed = 75;
[creatureList addObject:creature];
```

... and so forth. I've limited the array to 25 creatures right now until I find out where and how this information should be stored.

Comment: Use a plist file or database.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I don't know the entire scope of your project but the most appropriate way to handle this type of structured data is to store it in a database where it is easy to maintain and not hardcoded into your app. You can use a local database (Core Data, even just structured text files) or a remote database (mysql, mongodb, many others) which can load your list of creatures dynamically at runtime (or lazily, when it's needed).

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be doing this in CoreData - this is quite a learning curve if you've never done this before though. Ray Wenderlich as always is a good place to get started with it but if you really do want to have an array declared all in a class somewhere, I would suggest actually making a total separate class for the array, not just putting it somewhere else in your view.

You could also look into property lists (this is probably going to be the easiest option) especially if you don't have to modify the data once the app is launched. Here is a good walkthrough to doing  [this](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new and haven't familiarized myself with CoreData or plists but I think that's what I need. I'll be checking out those links.

Answer (score 0):

This is very inefficient and you would have a hard time maintaining your code.

I would put all the properties in a file (a .plist, a csv, text, database, whatever you want), and make your class read this file and instantiate a `CreatureObject` for each *item* found in the file (where item depends on your file, e.g. on a csv an item would be one line in the file).

In pseudo code

```
open config file
for (each line in file)
{
     Creature x = parse line
     arrayofCreatures addObject:x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

500 objects in an array, each object having 6 properties is not *Very large.* Arrays are meant to deal with collections.

If you want persistent data then no doubt you can go with CoreData,  SQLite, Database, or even you can form a plist to store the array.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd put all those data in a spreadsheet, export it as a CSV file.  Maybe put it into S3 to be downloaded on the fly.  That way you can tune and tweak your creatures attributes without updating your code (granted that your users are connected via Wi-Fi / cellular).

You should always include a default one in your iOS project in case the S3 container is not reachable.  Upon grabbing the CSV file, persist it in CoreData.  Have the app periodically check S3 for any changes.

To process the CSV file, use Dave Delong's [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest and most convenient way to handle data like your is to have a JSON file that describes all your creatures.

Among its various benefits (readability, easy to extend data structure), it allows you to easily change from a "embedded solution" (data inside your app) to a "remote solution" (data downloaded from a server).

An example of JSON loading in Swift:

```
var creatures = [Creature]()

do {

   let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
   let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
   let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)

   creatures = (jsonObject as? [[String: Any]]).flatMap({ Creature(dictionary: $0) })

} catch let exc {

   print(exc)
   return
}
```